# Assign group averages to each row in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe and I am looking to calculate the mean based on store and all stores.  I created code to calculate the mean but I am looking for a way that is more efficient.

DF

```
Cashier#     Store#     Sales    Refunds
001          001        100      1
002          001        150      2
003          001        200      2
004          002        400      1
005          002        600      4
```

DF-Desired

```
Cashier#     Store#     Sales    Refunds     Sales_StoreAvg    Sales_All_Stores_Avg
001          001        100      1            150               290
002          001        150      2            150               290
003          001        200      2            150               290
004          002        400      1            500               290
005          002        600      4            500               290
```

My Attempt
I created two additional dataframes then did a left join

```
df.groupby(['Store#']).sum().reset_index().groupby('Sales').mean()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for a new column filled with aggregate values computed by `mean`:

```
df['Sales_StoreAvg'] = df.groupby('Store#')['Sales'].transform('mean')
df['Sales_All_Stores_Avg'] = df['Sales'].mean()
print (df)
   Cashier#  Store#  Sales  Refunds  Sales_StoreAvg  Sales_All_Stores_Avg
0         1       1    100        1             150                 290.0
1         2       1    150        2             150                 290.0
2         3       1    200        2             150                 290.0
3         4       2    400        1             500                 290.0
4         5       2    600        4             500                 290.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this, with `transform` and `assign`:

```
df.assign(Sales_StoreAvg = df.groupby('Store#')['Sales'].transform('mean'),
          Sales_All_Stores_Avg = df['Sales'].mean()).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   Cashier#  Store#  Sales  Refunds  Sales_All_Stores_Avg  Sales_StoreAvg
0         1       1    100        1                   290             150
1         2       1    150        2                   290             150
2         3       1    200        2                   290             150
3         4       2    400        1                   290             500
4         5       2    600        4                   290             500
```